# derivative of determinat

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant

For a  lower trinagular, invertible but asymmetric matrix $X$, how to calculate the following:
$$
\frac{\partial |XX^T|^{-1/2}}{\partial X}
$$

I was doing the derivation, but not sure whether it was correct.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial |XX^T|^{-1/2}}{\partial X}&=& \frac{\partial |X|^{-1}}{\partial X}= -1\times|X|^{-1-1}\frac{\partial |X|}{\partial X}\\
&=& - |X|^{-2}|X|X^{-T}= -|X|^{-1}X^{-T}\\
&=& -|XX^T|^{-1/2} |X|^{-T}
\end{eqnarray*}  where $X^{-T}$ is transpose of inverse of $X$. My intention is to get the derivative of logarithm of pdf of multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu, XX^T)$ w.r.t to X where X is cholesky decomposition of covariance matrix. So, X is a lower triangular matrix. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My first question would be: What does it mean to differentiate a scalar-valued function of a matrix-valued random variable.  I can think of a way of answering that, and I'm not sure that it's taken into account in what is done above.

Comment: Hello @Micheal Hardy, thanks for your response. Covariance matrix can be written as $XX^T$. Then for gradient search algorithm for elements of covariance matrix, derivative of the above is needed. But i am not sure what i did was right or not.

Comment: Yeah, everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Shuchang Zhang. Here X is lower triangular matrix, but the derivative is upper triangular. I was thinking that derivative of lower triangular matrix would also be lower triangular. Is that right?

Comment: @tanus Not exactly, it depends how you define the derivative of the scalar w.r.t a matrix. The matrix calculus you used here happened to have an extra transpose. Just like the derivative of a scalar w.r.t a column vector is a row vector.